# How to fix this strange Readme in my github

Tags: github, markdown

On GitHub, my README file looks like this:

[image: picture1]

I don't know why those effects, shown in red frame happen. Here is my source text:

````
# bn_tool  
Big number tool  
## support  
```
mod exp  
mod inv  
mod  
exp  
add  
sub  
mul  
```

## make  
gcc calc.c -lcrypto -o calc.o  

## usage  
To calculate `65451^4660 mod 26505`:  
`./calc.o mod_exp "FFAB" "1234" "6789"`  

To calculate `11806078888327 * 3`:  
`./calc.o mod_exp "ABCD1236987" "03"`  

To calculate `k*G` which G is the basepoint of secp256k1 `./calc.o ec_mul secp256k1 "cef147652aa90162e1fff9cf07f2605ea05529ca215a04350a98ecc24aa34342"`
````

In notepad, it looks like this:

[image: picture2]

Comment: With a search I was able to locate what I assume is your [GitHub project](https://github.com/mrpre/bn_tool/blob/master/README.md) and I do not see the problem you describe. Can you provide more information, including the specific file on GitHub, what browser you are using, etc.

Comment: Your browser is injecting its own CSS or rendering it that way for some other reason. It doesn't look like that on Chrome.

Comment: Finally, i find those effects only exist in `preview changes` mode...